# TFS workflow variable for git repository root

Tags: git, tfs, workflow-foundation

I am migrating code into git repositories hosted by TFS. I have a custom build template based on the git default template with an InvokeProcess activity. I want to invoke an executable in my git repository. The the default working directory of InvokeProcess is apparently System32, so how can I determine the path of the git repository on the build agent?

Searching around there is apparently a [SourcesDirectory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1755082b-e7a5-4d63-b38d-23974f02f769/how-to-invoke-a-batch-file-in-a-different-directory-than-the-solution-using-invoke-process?forum=tfsbuild) variable defined in the workflow template for TFS VC, but it is not available to me with the git template. Is there another way to find out what this path is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a GetBuildDirectory activity to the workflow template. That stores the working directory for the build agent in a workflow variable, say BuildDirectory, and the source directory is under the "src" subdirectory of that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [GetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn231755.aspx) activity and get the [WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.activities.extensions.wellknownenvironmentvariables.sourcesdirectory.aspx) variable.